# Execute a method/set property in a specific thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, invoke

Hi everyone
I am kind of new to all of this multithreading stuff so please excuse me if I explain this badly :)

Let's say I have two classes:

```
class abc {
    public string SomeProperty {
        get { return something; }
        set { /* This code has to execute in the main application thread */ }
    }

    public void SomeMethod() {
        /* This code also has to execute in the main application thread */
    }
}

class def {
    abc obj;

    public def() {
        abc = new obj();
    }

    public void SomeMethod() {
        abc.SomeProperty = "SomeValue";
        abc.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is getting SomeProperty and SomeMethod to execute on the main application thread. I have tried:

```
abc.GetType().InvokeMember("SomeProperty", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, abc, new object[] { "SomeValue" });
abc.GetType().InvokeMember("SomeMethod", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, abc, null);
```

However, the code which needs to execute in the main application thread isn't being executed in the main application thread, even using InvokeMember (I don't think so anyway)
I have tried outputting the current thread name in the code, and it doesn't output the main application thread name.

Is there a way that I can do this?
If I have explained things badly just let me know :)
Thanks!

Comment: Please explain **why** you need to execute that code on the main (or whatever else) thread. Your approach using `InvokeMember` is just plain wrong and without clarifying your intent you can't expect a really useful answer that will match your actual case.

Comment: And please specify WinForms or WPF

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information. This is not WinForms or WPF, it's a Console Application. There are lot's of reasons why it needs to be executed on the main thread, one of which is because I am building an application which uses the Lidgren Network Library, and I can only send network messages on the thread which the library is listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InvokeMember` is just a way of executing a member using reflection. It has nothing to do with threading.

I suspect you're really looking for [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) or [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) (or the non-blocking `BeginInvoke` equivalents).

You'll need a reference to an appropriate control or dispatcher, of course, and then create an appropriate delegate to execute on another thread. If you look for a tutorial on Windows Forms multithreading (or WPF) you should find lots of examples. (My network connection is rubbish at the moment, otherwise I'd find a decent one for you.)

EDIT: Now that you've made it clear it's a console app, you'll have to work out some form of message pump. Unless a thread is *listening* for messages somehow, there's no way of forcing it to execute another bit of code. I haven't used the library you've talked about - but if it's forcing you to execute code on a particular thread, then it should provide some equivalent of `Control.Invoke` etc.

Comment: Bit confused here. I don't think I can use Control.Invoke because this isn't related to System.Windows.Forms objects. Can I use BeginInvoke, would that execute it in the thread I want? Or should I investigate into this Dispatcher.Invoke thing?

Comment: @Jamie: You haven't given us enough information about the context. What sort of application are you writing? You talk about a "main application thread" - but that thread will have to be running a message pump or something similar if you're going to be able to ask it to run arbitrary code.

Comment: I'm looking into BeginInvoke and I think it's exactly what I need. Is it possible to get hold of a delegate from MethodInfo which I can call BeginInvoke on? I have a very large amount of methods and I don't really want to go through each one and make a delegate for them. Thanks

Comment: @Jamie: No, you don't want to call BeginInvoke *on* the delegate. You want to pass the delegate *into* BeginInvoke. And you should look at Delegate.CreateDelegate to create a delegate from a MethodInfo.

Comment: Oh, I just found an article on MSDN. Would Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegateobj, etc) work?

Comment: @Jamie: Not for a console app, no.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do this, but my preferred approach is as follows:

```
   protected void setTransactionButton(Boolean enabled)
    {
        (new Task(() =>
        {
            transcriptQuitButton.Enabled = enabled;
        })).Start(uiScheduler);
    }
```

In my initialization code I had called this:

```
uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

What this does is to have the event take place on the UI thread and get rid of the need for `BeginInvoke`.

There are various places where you can find for `BeginInvoke`, but if you can use anonymous functions, and one article on that is here:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/02/01/use-lambda-expressions-for-abstract-delegates.aspx